# How to adjust font size of the td elements in a table which has a fixed width of 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, width

I wanted my `table` to be as wide as my browser window, so I wrote -

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I wanted my `td` and `th` elements to have a relative font size. By which I mean, they will appear smaller in smaller devices or smaller browser windows so that the table stays 100% wide

Any suggestion how to achieve that? Thanks in advance

N.B: I am generating the table from javascript and then appending it into the DOM for some other reasons